# QEMU .qcow2 mmu_gva_to_gpa crash in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qemu, kvm

I am trying to run my `.qcow2` image in Mac OS X with `qemu-system-x86_64`, it works perfectly fine on my Debian machine but for memory problems I need to move it to a Mac OS X Catalina machine. I installed `qemu-system-x86_64` through `brew` and then when I launch my machine with

```sh
qemu-system-x86_64 \
>   -m 8G \
>   -vga virtio \
>   -show-cursor \
>   -usb \
>   -device usb-tablet \
>   -enable-kvm \
>   -drive file=/Volumes/enricoWD/transfer_home_laptop/dxcator_home_backup_feb2020/diag-stage.qcow2,if=virtio \
>   -accel hvf \
>   -cpu host
```

it starts but after 4 seconds crashes with:

> vmx_write_mem: mmu_gva_to_gpa ffff9ac27b23fcdc failed
>
> Abort trap: 6

I saw other users encountered this problem here, but no answer provided.

If anybody has a clue, or suggestion for other ways to run my .qcow2 machine on Mac OS X it would be great! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could try `MacPorts` version perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix a similar problem using two different methods related to [QEMU / KVM CPU model configuration](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-cpu-models.html).
Both used Homebrew's port of QEMU, version 5.1.

### Option #1: Specify the CPU Model

Try specifying the CPU model which most closely matches the host machine.

1. Determine the CPU type of the host machine.

```
$ sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.brand_string
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4690 CPU @ 3.50GHz
```

2. Find the matching CPU model supported by QEMU.

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu help
```

A search at [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html), for `i5-4690` yields only one 3.5 GHz option, so [this](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/80813/intel-core-i5-4690t-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) is my CPU.
Using the `Product Collection` and `Code Name`, this CPU must correspond to the `x86 Haswell-v4` model.

3. Substitute the CPU model in the QEMU command.

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu Haswell-v4 ...
```

### Option #2: Emulate the CPU

If you still have issues, you can try emulating the CPU instead of using host passthrough.
This just requires using the [default `qemu64` CPU type](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-cpu-models.html?#default-x86-cpu-models).
You can do this like so:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu qemu64 ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Disable huge pages

> -cpu host,-pdpe1gb

Comment: This worked for me, but would be nice to know why is this happening and why is this the solution xD

Comment: First read it https://superuser.com/questions/710870/which-cpus-support-1gb-pages

Comment: Macos doesn't support huge pages. Or it need something settings, I don't know.

Comment: This worked for me too, but my host hardware is a MacBook, and my host OS is macOS, so I'm surprised `-cpu host` doesn't just work. How come?

Comment: @minseong 1gb pages is a cpu hardware feature. I think Macos use it in the kernel, but does not allow use in user mode. When the guest kernel tries to use it, then the host kernel raises an exception.